# Can't create dummy C# sensor class without getting no constructors defined error?

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have a C# Windows Phone 8 app that for phones that have it, uses the Compass sensor for a particular feature.  I want to modify the class so that it can work on phones that don't have a compass sensor.  I don't want to have to wrap every call to the Compass object in *if (_compass != null)* statements.  I thought I could create a dummy **Compass** class with stubs for the Compass methods and properties, and create an instance of it instead of Compass if the phone doesn't have a compass, but I'm running into a problem with the abstract base class for the Compass class called **SensorBase**.  No matter what I do, I get the compile time error:

```
Error   1   The type 'Microsoft.Devices.Sensors.SensorBase<TSensorReading>' has no constructors defined
```

The Compass class I'm trying to emulate *can* inherit from SensorBase without getting this error.  I grabbed the exact declaration line for the Compass class, from the Sensors metadata file, and plugged it into my dummy class after changing the class name to **CompassDummy**, and I still get the error.

My guess is that the Compass class can inherit from SensorBase while my dummy class can't because it is in the same Assembly as SensorBase.  Perhaps the constructor for SensorBase is marked *internal* or there is some other similar "friend" like relationship involved.

My question is, is there anything I can do in this situation to inherit from SensorBase without getting this error?  If not, is there another solution involving dependency injection (IOC) that would help achieve my goal of instantiating a dummy class when the phone doesn't have a compass?

Here is my code for the CompassDummy class that is getting the error:

```
public sealed class CompassDummy : SensorBase<CompassReading>
{
    public CompassDummy()
    {

    }
} // public class CompassDummy
```

Comment: Do you get the same error if you remove the constructor from your CompassDummy class?

Answer (score 4):

> My guess is that the Compass class can inherit from SensorBase while my dummy class can't because it is in the same Assembly as SensorBase. Perhaps the constructor for SensorBase is marked internal

Correct. You're not supposed to derive from `SensorBase<T>` yourself: it's just the base class for `Accelerometer`, `Compass`, `Gyroscope`, and `Motion`.

Are you planning to just use this dummy `Sensor` class within your own code, and not pass it anywhere? If so, use composition rather than inheritance here:

```
public interface ICompass
{
   void Start();
   // Whatever other methods you need
}

public class RealCompass : ICompass
{
   private readonly Compass compass;

   public RealCompass(Compass compass)
   {
      this.compass = compass;
   }

   public void Start()    
   {
      this.compass.Start();
   }
}


public class StubCompass : ICompass
{
   public void Start()
   {
      // Do nothing...
   }
}
```

Then, in your code, use your `ICompass` interface.

Comment: Right, but then I do have to create a wrapper method for everything the Compass object  exposes publicly since the Compass object doesn't declare my ICompass interface.  It's a real shame that Anders Heljsberg who helped design C# did not add the Delphi implements delegate feature to C#.  Time to write some plumbing code.

Comment: @RobertOschler It's true. In practice though, `Compass` is a pretty small class and it will only take you a few minutes to write the wrapper. The language design discussion for C# 7 is still open: if you've got a feature suggestion, now is the time to make it! See the Roslyn GitHub repo.

Comment: Wrapper done.  Definitely looking forward to C# 7 and Roslyn.

Answer (score 1):

Using an interface to allow substitution of the concrete compass type, [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31102216/cant-create-dummy-c-sharp-sensor-class-without-getting-no-constructors-defined#31102734) by canton7, is a good solution to this problem. Another solution to consider, depending on your needs, is the [proxy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Proxy_pattern).

Basically, you'd create a `CompassProxy` class that you'd use throughout your code. This class would have similar or identical methods/properties to the framework [`Compass`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br225705) class, and each instance of it would contain a corresponding instance of either `Compass` or `CompassDummy`, depending on the phone's hardware.

Calls to the proxy class would be forwarded to the contained "back-end" compass class, which would do the real work and any result would then be passed back through to the caller.

Just as an illustration, here is some prototype code for a CompassProxy class:

```
class CompassProxy {

    private readonly Compass _realCompass = null;
    private readonly CompassDummy _dummyCompass = null;

    private readonly bool _hasCompass = false;


    public CompassProxy() {

        // the creation logic could be moved out of this class, if need be
        if ( HasRealCompassHardware() ) {

            _realCompass = Compass.GetDefault();  // ...or whatever is the proper way to obtain an instance
            _hasCompass = true;

        } else {

            _dummyCompass = new CompassDummy();

        }

    }


   public CompassReading GetCurrentReading() {

        return _hasCompass ? _realCompass.GetCurrentReading() : _dummyCompass.GetCurrentReading();

    }

}
```

Comment: See my comment to canton7 below.  That's what I'll end up doing.  It's still basically the same as the "if (_instance !- null)" technique though.

Comment: @RobertOschler Yeah, it boils down to the same work in practice, just a matter of how you want to factor the logic. And I agree, it would be nice if C# offered an elegant alternative to the grunt work of writing pass-through code.